# why does the mesh generated by CGAL contain additional triangles?

Tags: cgal

I am working with CGAL to generate a 2D unstructured mesh in a triangle. The code is shown below.

```
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds> CDT;
typedef CDT::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
CDT cdt;
Vertex_handle va = cdt.insert(Point(-4,0));
Vertex_handle vb = cdt.insert(Point(0,-1));
Vertex_handle vc = cdt.insert(Point(4,0));
cdt.insert_constraint(va, vb);
cdt.insert_constraint(vb, vc);
cdt.insert_constraint(vc, va);
CGAL::refine_Delaunay_mesh_2(cdt, Criteria(0.125, 0.5));
```

The resulting mesh is shown below. 
[image]

At first glance, the mesh is good. However, when I zoom in the figure, I find that there are a lot of additional edges:
[image]

So what's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remember a triangulation in CGAL has the same topologically as a triangulation on a sphere. For this purpose, an additional vertex called the infinite vertex is added and all edges of the convex hull of the input points are connected to this infinite vertex. Did you pay attention to filter out infinite edges and faces?

Comment: In the lower image, the topmost line: It looks like it intersects the triangle? What did you use as a viewing/plotting software. Maybe we see inaccuracy from the viewing end?